# JSLink: Userfields (Author, Editor, ...) only provide userId not username

Tags: 2013, jslink, client-side-rendering

i recently tried to modify a view with JSLink, modification works very good, but userfields are not correct provided if JSLink is in use.
By default a userfield is rendered blank at first glance. Looking into HTML it renders as

```
<span class="ms-floatLeft ms-peopleux-vanillaUser">
   <span class="ms-floatLeft ms-peopleux-vanillaUser">
      <span class="ms-floatLeft ms-peopleux-vanillaUser">
         <span class="ms-floatLeft ms-peopleux-vanillaUser">
            <span class="ms-floatLeft ms-peopleux-vanillaUser">
</span></span></span></span></span>
```

Debugging context.CurrentItem provides that the given value is only the UserID
CurrentItem:

```
{
   Title: "Test", 
   Editor: "1", 
   PublishingPageContext:"...", 
   ...
}
```

JSLink:

```
(function () { 
    var bodyFiledContext = {}; 
    bodyFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
    bodyFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        "PublishingPageContent": { "View": bodyFiledTemplate }
    };  
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(bodyFiledContext); 
})();
```

Any chance to get the username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure user field is included into List View.

Then, you could access user field properties as shown on picture below

[image]

```
(function () { 

    function renderPageContent(rCtx){

        var item = rCtx.CurrentItem;
        if(item.Author.length > 0) {
           var authorId = item.Author[0].id; 
           var authorName = item.Author[0].title;            
        }
    }


    var viewContext = {}; 
    viewContext.Templates = {}; 
    viewContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        "PublishingPageContent": { "View": renderPageContent }
    };  
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(viewContext); 
})();
```

Comment: As you mention, it should be like this, but it was not. I only had the UserID String instead of a User Object although having userfield in view. This is very strange. I tried to write an other JSLink for an other List and it worked instantly. Back to this list i deleted the ListWebPart and added it anew, guess what? it worked... Atm i was not able to reproduce the first behavior.
Never the less thank you for your help!